# How to get #error (and not null) using a DataAdapter/DataSet

Tags: ssas, mdx, adomd.net

I've a MDX query:

```
with member [Measures].[Error Measure] as 1/[Measures].[Non Existing]
select [Measures].[Error Measure] on 0 from [MyCube]
```

where [Measures].[Non Existing] doesn't exist in MyCube.

If I try to execute this query in SSMS, I'll receive a cellSet with one cell and the content will be #error (and an explicit message in the tooltip).

On the other hand, if I create an AdomdCommand and execute this query with:

```cs
var adapter = new AdomdDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
var ds = new DataSet();  
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

I'll not receive an exception and my dataset will be loaded with a unique row with one unique column and the content will be null. I've investigated the GetColumnError() method but nothing is specified.

Is there a way to know that this cell is in error and not null (without changing to a cellSet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know a solution for `AdomdCommand`s, but within MDX: You can use the `IsError` method which actually is not an MDX, but a VBA method:

```
with member [Measures].[Error Measure] as 1/[Measures].[Non Existing]
     member [Measures].[Error Indicator] as IIf(IsError([Measures].[Error Measure]), 'error', 'ok')
     member [Measures].[Error or Orig] as IIf(IsError([Measures].[Error Measure]), 'error', [Measures].[Error Measure])
select { [Measures].[Error Measure], [Measures].[Error Indicator], [Measures].[Error or Orig] } on 0
from [MyCube]
```

Comment: Ok, not what I expected (I've been looking for something helpful so much that I think it's not possible to know that the column is on error with an adomdCommmand) but will probably use your VBA solution